# Quicker way to update container when changing Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I am new to Docker and the process I use to create and execute a container from a Dockerfile is the following:

1. `docker build -t (IMAGE_NAME) .`
2. `docker docker run -itd --name (CONTAINER_NAME) (IMAGE_NAME)`
3. `docker exec -it (CONTAINER_NAME) bash`

However, if I want to update my Dockerfile and run the container again I have to do the following:

1. `docker ps` to get the ID of my container
2. `docker container stop (ID)`
3. `docker rm (ID)`

and then I have to repeat the first three steps. Is there a quicker way to do this or have to rerun these steps every time I update my Dockerfile? This is very tedious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If time is a concern, enable [Buildkit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/), it is way faster to build.

```sh
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
```

You already figured out to use name on all 3 commands, you can combine all 3 commands

```sh
docker rm NAME; docker build -t NAME /absolutepath && docker docker run -itd --name NAME && docker exec -it NAME bash
```

I use `&&` (run next command when return code is 0=no error) on the execution commands and `;` (continue to next command, even on error e.g 'container not found') on the initial removal of the previous container. Since this won't stop the chain in case you forgot you already removed the container. As you also see I encourage you to use absolute path for `docker build` so it works in any directory, should you happen to move around slightly.

Comment: How would the command be if I used the absolute path for docker build? Could you please write it for me?

Comment: Thats for you to know, simply as it is shown in your filemanager (full path) or shell, but one way you can get it without knowing where to find it; goto your Dockerfile directory with cd and type `echo $PWD` you can also pipe that to clipboard with `xclip` if you have Xorg gui running `echo $PWD > xclip` (might require a package, like `xclip`)